# SQL SELECT statement with HAVING and OR

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has some users in it. They all have a username, latitude,longitude and some other fields.

I want to select all users within 5KM range of a given coordinate and based on some other criteria. Now this part was not hard.

However, I also want the SQL statement to return users with given usernames independently from the other criterias mentioned above.

So, basically, the SQL should return users based on the distance and other criterias AND users who have a specific username despite if they match the criterias or no.

Here is what I have, but it does not work:

```
SELECT idUser
     , username 
     , telephone
     , latitude
     , longitude
     , ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM main 
 WHERE active = ? 
   AND idUser != ? 
HAVING distance < 5 
    OR username = mike 
    OR username = john
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT idUser, username, telephone, latitude, longitude,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM main
WHERE active = ? AND idUser != ?
HAVING distance < 5 OR username IN ('mike', 'john');
```

You may need to remove the `idUser` . . . I'm not sure if that is related to `username` or not.

EDIT:

If you want to guarantee that mike and john are in the result set, you can do:

```
(SELECT idUser, username, telephone, latitude, longitude,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
 FROM main
 WHERE active = ? AND idUser != ? AND username NOT IN ('mike', 'john')
 HAVING distance < 5
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT idUser, username, telephone, latitude, longitude,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
 FROM main
 WHERE username IN ('mike', 'john')
)
```

Or:

```
SELECT idUser, username, telephone, latitude, longitude,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM main
WHERE (active = ? AND idUser <> ?) OR username IN ('mike', 'john')
HAVING distance < 5 OR username IN ('mike', 'john');
```

Or move all conditions to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT idUser, username, telephone, latitude, longitude,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM main
WHERE (active = ? AND idUser <> ?) OR username IN ('mike', 'john')
HAVING (active = ? AND idUser <> ? AND distance < 5) OR
       username IN ('mike', 'john');
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing, but this does not work. The reason is that I think it only selects users who have active as 0 (suppose ? is 0) and if mike does not have active as 0, it won't work